# Доступ к файлу в памяти в wxWidgets

Tags: html, c++, файлы, wxwidgets

У меня есть код, который записывает файл JPG в память:

```
wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile("radius.jpg",
        bmp.ConvertToImage(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_JPEG);
```

Я использовал его для просмотра в HTML-вьювере, и это отлично работало. Но когда я решил сохранять результат в виде единого html-файла (этому посвящен другой мой вопрос), то столкнулся с тем, что не могу получить доступ к этому файлу в памяти. Как получить объект типа `wxFile` для файла, хранящегося в памяти? Думал, что `"memory:radius.jpg"` в качестве имени (как в тэге `src`) будет достаточно, но оказалось, что это не так.

Как мне получить образ файла в памяти (или заново создать его из `wxImage`), чтобы потом преобразовать его в base64 и добавить в файл html?

Еще раз - моя сверхзадача состоит в сохранении результата, **уже** полностью имеющегося в памяти, в html-вьювере, в виде некоторого **одного** файла. Если я делаю глупость и есть какой-то простой метод - ткните меня в него носом ))